# SOAP on IOS - considering new approach

Tags: ios, soap, ssl, asihttprequest, afnetworking

Hey guys Im currently working on ios application which is requesting data using SOAP. Till this point i have been using ASIHTTPRequest to send request and handle response. But i realy can't get client certificate working (yes, i tried replacing code in if-statement in asihttprequest.m, and i also fixed many other bugs).

So due to this problem and to fact, this framework is not longer supported i have decided to use another framework. I am thinking about AFNetworking but it doesnt realy seem easy to use this one for SOAP and im not realy into overriding its method beacause im realy new to this whole apple/objective-c platform.

So what are you guys suggesting ? What is best way to send SOAP requests (and handle responses) to WS with client certificate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i've abandoned any 3rd party libraries and wrote the whole web service interface using NSURLConnection and NSMutableRequest. It was foolish to depend on 3rd party software. It is most definitely way to go, especially if you want to use client certificate you can use

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)con didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge ....
```